# Rotationated inertial frames and Galileo Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, relativity, linear-algebra, relative-motion

Consider then a inertial frame $S$ and another one, $S'$.
The inertial frame $S'$ is at uniform motion with respect to $S$.
Both inertial frames are the Euclidian vector spaces $\mathbb{E}^3$ equipped with an orthonormal basis. For $S$ we have the basis $\beta = [\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}]$ and for $S'$ we have the basis $\beta' = [\vec{i'},\vec{j'},\vec{k'}]$.
The coordinate transformation that (in a Newtonian physical sense) connects the two inertial frames are the Galileo Transformations:

$$ \vec{r'} = \vec{r} - \vec{V}t$$

Or, in component form:

$$ x' = x- v_{x}t \\ y' = y- v_{y}t \\z' = z- v_{z}t \\ t' = t $$

$$* * *$$

My question is, how can I include the rotational matrix in the transformations with vector algebra?

Something like:

$$ \vec{r} = R\vec{r'} + \vec{r'} + \vec{V}t$$

My reference is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: just read farther down the wikipedia page, because [it gets into this later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation#Galilean_group).

Perhaps a more useful answer specific to your needs is that it depends on what you want for the order of operations, but this works:
\begin{equation}
  \vec{r} = R\, \left( \vec{r}' + \vec{V}\, t \right).
  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
This equation says that you first "boost" the frame with velocity $\vec{V}$, and then rotate it by $R$.  Alternatively, if you want to rotate first and then boost, you would have
\begin{equation}
  \vec{r} = R\, \vec{r}' + \vec{V}\, t.
  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
These two can also be considered equivalent if you incorporate the rotation into $\vec{V}$.

Of course, you haven't described the entire Galilean group in this way; you also need to include *translations* (both space and time).  So, in general, you could include the space translation $\vec{a}$ and the time translation $s$ to get
\begin{align}
  \vec{r} &= R\, \vec{r}' + \vec{V}\, t' + \vec{a}, \tag{3a} \\
  t &= t' + s. \tag{3b}
\end{align}
Again, we have made a particular choice for the order of operations.  In this case, we first rotate by $R$, then "boost" by $\vec{V}$, and then translate by $\vec{a}$ and $s$.  So this is the general from of equation (2) above, rather than equation (1).

Comment: what is the precise physical difference between a translation and unifom motion?

Comment: The difference is that a translation is constant in time, whereas uniform motion is proportional to time — so it's like a *constantly growing* translation.  Take a look at my update.  In equation (3a), $\vec{V}t'$ represents the uniform motion (because it's proportional to $t'$), whereas $\vec{a}$ represents the translation (because it doesn't depend on $t'$).

Comment: a translation in time can be interpreted as a "desynchronicity"?